# ListView chat message for Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have created an app which involves chatting with other people, and to make the chat activity more pleasing to the eye I created a `ListView` to change the UI of each message. When I send a message the first message appears and displays correctly but if I send another message it overrides the previous message in the listView instead of just adding another value to the list view, here's my code:

ChatActivty:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
            chatList.add(chat);

            chatListAdapter adapter = new chatListAdapter(this, R.layout.chat_message, chatList);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);

        }
}
```

Chat List adapter:

```
public class chatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chat> {

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    TextView usernameTV, messageTV;

    public chatListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Chat> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String username = getItem(position).getUsername();
        String message = getItem(position).getMessage();

        Chat chat = new Chat(username, message);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        usernameTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.username_chat);
        messageTV = convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_chat);

        usernameTV.setText(username);
        messageTV.setText(message);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I won't add the other bits of code (the getter and setters or the actual layout of the individual messages) because I don't think that's a problem. Let me know if you need anything else, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here to make this happen,

Thanks, Nathan

EDIT:

I finally found out how to add to the listview without it overriding with this code:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
            chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

            Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
            chatList.add(chat);
            Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
            Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

with the array list and adpater being a public variable at the top, however it still shows the message twice. I still need to find a fix for that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, simply use only the following lines of code:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            chatList.add(ds.getValue(Chat.class));
        }
        chatListAdapter adapter = new chatListAdapter(this, R.layout.chat_message, chatList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The problem in your code is that your are creating a new instance of an `ArrayList` at every iteration, ending up having everytime only one item in the list.

**Edit:**

Seeing this, your database reference should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("matches").child("1").child("-LluNpbfFgzFclI7cdAS").child("messages");
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and got this error:  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.wasd.opposites.Chat

Comment: This means that you are using a wrong `DatabaseReference`. Please add your database structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it, the database reference points to this place, I'll send it over an image: https://imgur.com/a/e0F8PkS (Everytime the user sends a message it create a random string and in that node it has the message and username in it: https://imgur.com/a/muf5Rqo

Comment: In this case you should use the database reference `keyRef` as in my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: I understand that I have to use the keyRef reference, however, every message gets it's own key so it technically has to be dynamic. I can't hard code in a value as it's just a bunch of random values as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/Bl7QuBl is there any way around that?

Comment: There are 2 messages under `messages` node and that's fine will work for sure. If you are talking about the first hardcoded id `-LluNpbfFgzFclI7cdAS`, I just gave you an example. When you push that id, you need to store it in a variable in order to use it your reference, right?

Comment: It would work, but only for the person who sent the message since they're the only one with the pushed key, the other wont have that key becuase it was created on their client side, if that makes sense.

Comment: In this case you should change your database structure. You cannot achieve this with your actual schema. You should create a node where you need to host all messages within a conversation, right?

Comment: The things is the way my app works them messages are only temporary and they get deleted after like 5 minutes, users get matched together and they have 5 mins to talk to one another then it ends and the whole match gets deleted

Comment: Yes, I understand but this is the single way at which I can think of for solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a FirebaseListAdapter to display messages from firebase, and apply a custom layout to the messages in the list.

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    Query messages = database.getReference("chatrooms").child(sessionId).child("messages");

    FirebaseListOptions<Message> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Message>().setQuery(messages, Message.class).setLayout(R.layout.message).build();

    ListView messageList = chatActivity.findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Message>(options){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Message model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            // Set their text
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageBody());
            messageUser.setText(model.getUser());

            // Format the date before showing it
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                    model.getTime()));
        }
    };

    messageList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
```

See more here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

Comment: Thank you for the comment I'll have a look

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been struggling with this. I just missed the line   adapter.startListening();

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arrange like this:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.e("Chat details: ", String.valueOf(ds));
        chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
        chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);

        Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);
        chatList.add(chat);
        Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
        Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
    }
    chatListAdapter adapter = new chatListAdapter(this, R.layout.chat_message, chatList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Edited:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    chatListAdapter adapter = (chatListAdapter)mListView.getAdapter();

    chat_username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
    chat_msg = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
    Log.e("Chat username: ", "" + chat_username);
    Log.e("Chat message: ", "" + chat_msg);
    Chat chat = new Chat(chat_username, chat_msg);

    adapter.add(chat);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a go

Comment: I tried rearranging like you said and the message now appears twice in the list view then if I add another message it gets overridden again but shows it twice again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go, I need the for loop though don't I?